# How many times does this for loop run?

Tags: for-loop

```
int main()
{
 for(;;) {
      printf("INSIDE FOR LOOP");
      return 0;
     }
}
```

How many times is the printf statement gonna be printed? and why?

Comment: I don't think one should try to **`Answer`** Such **`Question`**. As it is really waste to **answer** if some-one can't try to do his **`home-work`** !

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Compiler Reaction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555065/c-compiler-reaction)

Comment: stop nonsense Luv. If u can answer the qstn, please answer it. And FYI this is no way my homework. I wanted to know how does the compiler receive this statement. Does the compiler ignore this??

Answer (score 3):

The statement is printed 1 time. The `return` exits the loop and the program.

Answer (score -4):

It loops forever because there is no condition (what normally goes *between* the `;;`).